# LINQ Help to a specific questrion to sum some things depending on their same category

Tags: linq, database-design

I have an entity. A table named TABLE with 2 columns and 6 rows, and a connection to Database called db.

car        50

paper       3

paper       4

dictionary  3

car        30

computer   10

How can I create a NEWLIST from this that will show like this:

car 80

paper 7

dictionary 3

computer 10

var NEWLIST = db.Table ....LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your entity which represent the table has 2 properties, `Name` and `Amount` ( of type Int)

```
public class Item
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public int Amount { set;get;}
}
```

And your dbContext class has a property of type DbSet of Item

```
public class YourDbContext
{
  public DbSet<Item> Items { set;get;}
}
```

You can group by the name and then do a sum on the other property.

```
var db = new YourDbContext();
var result = db.Items.GroupBy(s => s.Name, p => p, (k, v) => 
                     new Item { Name = k, Amount = v.Sum(d => d.Amount)}).ToList();
```